# What´s wrong with this angularjs code?

Tags: angularjs

I wrote this angularjs and html code inside a .cshtml file using Visual Studio 2013 to study the behavior of element.wrap(elements). But it is not working as I expected.

```html
@{
Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleapp">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<title>Directives</title>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module("exampleapp", []).directive("demoDirective", function ()
{
return function (scope, element, attrs)
{
var listElem = angular.element("<ol>");
element.append(listElem);
for(var i=0;i<scope.names.length;i++)
{
listElem.append(angular.element("<li>").append(angular.element("<span>").text(scope.names[i])));
}
var listElemClone = listElem.clone();
element.append(listElemClone);
var myarray = angular.copy(scope.names);
myarray.reverse();
var listElemx = angular.element("<ol>");
element.prepend(listElemx);
for (var j = 0; j < myarray.length; j++) {
var lixvar = angular.element("<span>").css('color', 'red').css('font-weight', 'bold').text(myarray[j]).wrap(angular.element("<li>"));
lixvar.wrap(listElemx);
}
var searchresults = listElemx.find('li');
for (var i = 0; i < searchresults.length; i++)
{
if(searchresults.eq(i).children().eq(0).text()=='Apple')
{
searchresults.eq(i).replaceWith(angular.element("<span>").css('color', 'green').css('font-weight', 'bold').text('Waruna').wrap(angular.element('<li>')));
}
}
};
}).controller("defaultctrl", function ($scope) {
$scope.names = ["Apple","Bananas","Oranges"];
});
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="defaultctrl">
<h3>Fruit</h3>
<div demo-directive></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I used Visual studio 2013 to write this code. Here is a screen shot of the result...
[image: Screenshot]

As you can see the `<li></li>` are not created while using wrap().

Actually in the working code `<li></li>` elements are created. Here is a screen shot of the web page created by a working code(using append() except wrap()).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: 1. Seem like `jQuery.wrap()` return **wrapped** element instead of new created `DOM` element. 2. The object that is used to `wrap` does not update it `content` after using for wrapping. ie. `lixvar.wrap(listElemx)`. `listElemx` content will not be updated to consist of `lixvar`, to get the whole new `DOM` object including the `wrapped element`, you can use `jQuery.parent()`. ie. `var newElem =  lixvar.wrap(listElemx).parent()`.

Comment: Your answer is correct brother. Thank you a lot.